# JW Player embedding RTMP from S3

Tags: video, amazon-s3, jwplayer, rtmp

I am really struggling with understanding why what the code I am writing is not loading the video. I am getting an error saying video not found but it is there. Ii think its a problem with how I am embedding.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d22dpplejhrt07.cloudfront.net/jwplayer.js"></script>

                <div id="mediaplayer">This text will be replaced</div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
                        flashplayer: "https://d22dpplejhrt07.cloudfront.net/player.swf",
                        file: "rtmp://s12djcvw3migda.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:finalSW.mp4",
                        backcolor: "000000",
                        frontcolor: "FFFFFF",
                        autostart: "true",
                        controlbar: "bottom",
                        width: "550px",
                        height: "309px"
                    });
                </script>
```

The player is located on S3 and I created a web distribution and the video file I created a RTMP distribution.

I really cannot get my head around why this is not working, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JW5, you need to use file / streamer separately.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/31145/rtmp-streaming